# Spring Social - Get extended permissions for Facebook friends

Tags: java, facebook, spring-social

I am using **Spring Social**, and its **Facebook** integration.

I am trying to fetch details of the current user's friends (such as Location, etc.), but the result is always empty. Now, I believe that this is because this is available only with "**user_location**" or "**friends_location**" **extended permission**.

I am wondering how can I authorize my application for those permissions of the user, and successfully fetch the details like friend's location?

Just to reiterate - this has to be done within my Spring Social project.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How have you done it? I mean, I'm trying to accomplish the same here, and the correct answer below does not provide that much of detail, it looks like I'd have to write my own implementation for facebook stuff, is there anywhere where I can set this authorization url using SpringSocial?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can authorize your application for those permissions of the user in the following way

```
    "redirect:https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?" +
     "scope=" + userPermissions + 
     "&client_id=" + clientId +
     "&display=page&redirect_uri=" + redirectURI;
```

Where userPermissions is what are the permissions you need, clientId is your facebook appId, and redirectURI is where you go after authorizing (this must be same as your app's site url).

You can also fetch your friend details successfully by

http://static.springsource.org/spring-social-facebook/docs/1.0.x/reference/html/apis.html#facebook-getProfile

Comment: Specially read 3.2 Getting a user's Facebook friends of above url.